# Addin unique styling for last (not last) child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Faced with an interesting problem, I have .child.red children, the number of which is growing or decreasing dynamically, I need to refer to the last .child.red element, can this be done with styles? I already tried it, unique, but it is interesting to consider the behavior with you: the last child. funny. I will be grateful html
**html**

```css
.child {
  background: blue;
}
.child.red:first-child {
  background: red;
}
.child.red:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child red">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    7
  </div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**//// css**

Comment: Can't read your Text but maybe try last-of-type?

Comment: Stack overflow is English only site. Check out the [dedicated sites for other language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297734#297734)

Comment: Please post your question in English

Comment: If I can not read, I can not help.

Answer (score 0):

You are either going to have to add a class to the last `red` child and match the class in css or use JavaScript to select the last `red` child and append a class.

See example below for a JS solution:

```js
var redElements = document.querySelectorAll(".red");
var lastRedElement = redElements[redElements.length -1];
lastRedElement.classList.add("last");
```

```css
.child {
  background: blue;
}
.child.red:first-child {
  background: red;
}
.child.red.last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child red">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    7
  </div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```